# UML class diagram relation with mother class if every child class uses the same thing

Tags: singleton, uml, class-diagram

I have two questions:

1. I have a Singleton class with a property `Layout` that I use in creating child objects of an abstract class (example below). The abstract class has an abstract method where the layout file is given as a variable. Do I connect that Singleton class to the abstract class or each child? The following example is written using pseudo-code:

   ```
   public class SingletonClass
   {
       public static Instance;
       public var[,] Layout;
   }

   public abstract class AbstractClass
   {
       public abstract void DoSomething(var[,] Layout);
   }

   public class ClassA : AbstractClass
   {
       public override void  DoSomething(var[,] Layout) { some code }
   }

   public class ClassB : AbstractClass
   {
       public override void  DoSomething(var[,] Layout) { some other code }
   }
   ```
2. Is it even needed, or "cleaner", to give the Layout as variable in the method, or is it ok to just call Layout from the singleton class?

Comment: I don't know which language that is (guessing JavaScript or so). `Layout` is untyped in that code. So you don't have any relation. I'd use a dependency from SC to AC.

Comment: It's a pseudo code

Comment: Ok, but then what kind of language: typed or untyped?

Comment: Typed, I'm working in C#.

Comment: Ok. Late here. I'll answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The following UML is an equivalent of your code

[image]

under the following assumptions: `Instance` and `Layout` are assumed to be attributes of analogous classes.

`SingletonClass` has two owned attributes (denoted by the big dots): public `layout` of type `Layout` and `instance` of type `AbstractClass` (it's abstract, hence the italics). The latter will later hold either an instance of the concrete `ClassA` or `ClassB`.

Whether or not the design is ok depends. Basically there's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: I now see why the layout part was unclear. The Layout is a 2d array stored on the Singleton class, which is holding instances of the childs of the abstract class. This doesn't change anything though, besides moving Layout into SingltonClass. I've updated it in the code above. Also, with "The latter will later hold either an instance of the concrete ClassA or ClassB. ", do you mean that there won't be an extra relation to SingleTon?

Comment: `layout` **is** already inside `SingletonClass` (the dot). It just is missing the multiplicity then.

Comment: Why should there be a relation to `SingletonClass`? There is none.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Of course. I had been mixed up with interfaces. Updated,